# What is the best way of cycling through an array with buttons on SwiftUi?

Tags: arrays, swift, button, calendar

I am relatively new to swift and am stuck juggling many concepts trying to figure out how to get the Months to change via a button press. I have only seen this question answered for storyboards.

```
struct CalendarView : View{
    var Months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November","December"]
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width:352)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            Months -= 1 
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName:"chevron.backward")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                        Text(Months [0])
                        Button {
                            Months += 1
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName:"chevron.right")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using `@IBAction` and `@IBOutlet` to no avail because it became quite convoluted.

Comment: What actual problem are you having with the code you posted? Update your question with relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Lets correct the obvious mistakes first:

1. The `var Months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November","December"]` is acctually a constant, and should not be capitalized:

```
let months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November","December"]
```

Note: it's even better not to hard-code such information, but that is a bigger issue, not going to address it here.

2. The statements `Months += 1` and `Months -= 1` are invalid (you can't navigate array like that), what you actually need is some variable that keeps the currently selected month, so lets introduce: `var currentMonth = 0` and replace `Months += 1` and `Months -= 1` with

```
currentMonth = min(currentMonth + 1, months.count - 1)
```

and

```
currentMonth = max(currentMonth - 1, 0)
```

Those statements allow you to update current month, but without exceeding the minimal or maximal index

3. Instead of hardcoding `Text(Months [0])` (that is display "January" no matter what), we want to display the current month, so lets do this instead:

```
Text(months[currentMonth])
```

4. Finally: to make sure that month is actually changing, we need to tell the view to update on `currentMonth` change. To do that, we modify `currentMonth` to be a `@State`, i.e. change that variable to:

```
@State var currentMonth = 0
```

So here's the final version:

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    
    let months = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November","December"]
    @State var currentMonth = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width:352)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            currentMonth = max(currentMonth - 1, 0)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName:"chevron.backward")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                        Text(months[currentMonth])
                        Button {
                            currentMonth = min(currentMonth + 1, months.count - 1)
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName:"chevron.right")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I needed exactly. I am still learning so I'm so thankful for you.